# principle laurent series of $f(z)=\frac{(e^z-1)(1-\cos(2z))}{z^4\sin(z)}$ at $z=0$ and determine $\oint_{|z|=1} f(z)dz$.

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Question:
So given the function $$f(z)=\frac{(e^z-1)(1-\cos(2z))}{z^4\sin(z)}.$$
First: Give the principal part of the Laurent series of $f$ at $z = 0$.

Second: Determine the integral $\oint_{|z|=1} f(z)dz$.

I don't know where to start with this problem so I hope somebody can help me out.

Comment: It should be *principal*.

Comment: if $f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k z^k$  then $\frac{f(z)}{z^4} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k z^{k-4}$ and for computing $\int_{|z|=1} \frac{f(z)}{z^4}dz$, if $f(z)$ is holomorphic on $|z| \le 1$, then you are interested only in the value of $c_3$. note that you can also use directly the [Cauchy integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Theorem) (but proving it first is better)

Comment: Would you mind me showing how to calculate all this ? Because it is still not very clear to me.

Comment: Notice that $$f(z) = \frac{(e^{z}-1)(1- \cos(2z))}{z^{4} \sin(z)} = \frac{2(e^{z}-1) \sin(z)}{z^{4}} = \frac{2(e^{z}-1) \sin(z)}{(z-0)^{4}} = \frac{g(z)}{(z-0)^{4}}$$ and it is then a straight forward application of the Cauchy integral formula as user1952009 stated, as $g(z)$ is holomorphic.